# RegEx to match the last item with Breakline

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the last url by RegEx but result is not my expectation.

Is RegEx able to get the last line? If you know something this please help me.

I'm using python3.7 for it.

Thank you.

Source:

```
lorem is usum
foobar
[text_link_example](http://text-link.com)
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
http://link-2.com
text_without_space
http://url-i-want-to-get...
```

Regex I used

```
http[^ \]]+...$
```

Expectation

```
http://url-i-want-to-get...
```

What I got

```
http://link-2.com
text_without_space
http://url-i-want-to-get...
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
I'm using python3.7

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen @ Emma
Both of answer work for me.
Thank both of you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick approach would be to use `re.findall` to match all URLs, then just retain the last list element:

```
inp = """lorem is usum
foobar
[text_link_example](http://text-link.com)
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
http://link-2.com
text_without_space
http://url-i-want-to-get..."""

last_url = re.findall(r'https?://\S+', inp)[-1]
print(last_url)
```

This prints:

```
http://url-i-want-to-get...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
http.*\.{3}
```

or,

```
https?:\/\/.*\.{3}
```

might simply work OK here.

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
lorem is usum
foobar
[text_link_example](http://text-link.com)
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
http://link-2.com
text_without_space
http://url-i-want-to-get...
Regex I used
'''

expression = r'(?m)https?:\/\/.*\.{3}'

print(re.search(expression, string).group(0))

print(re.findall(expression, string))

for item in re.finditer(expression, string):
    print(item.group(0))
```

#### Output

```
http://url-i-want-to-get...
['http://url-i-want-to-get...']
http://url-i-want-to-get...
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gh1K12/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gh1K12/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---